# Undefined Symbols for Architecture and Linker Error - Can't Figure out Why

Tags: linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I have to copy and expand upon some code for a data structures class. It's a template for a linked list as an ADT. I'm getting some errors, but after spending several hours looking into what they are and combing my code, I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm missing. I've seen other people have posted about the same error, but looking at what was wrong with their code, I don't seem to have those issues - or if I do, I'm totally over-looking it.

So here are the .h, .cpp, and main, followed by the exact errors:

```
#ifndef nodeType_h
#define nodeType_h

template<class Type>
struct nodeType
{
    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};

#endif /* nodeType_h */

#ifndef LinkedList_h
#define LinkedList_h

#include "LinkedListIterator.h"
#include "nodeType.h"

template <class Type>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    const LinkedList<Type>& operator=(const LinkedList<Type>&);
    // Function to overload the assignment operator.

    void initializeList();
    // Function to initialize like to an empty state.
    // Precondition: A full list is passed for clearing.
    // Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;

    bool isEmptyList() const;
    // Function to determine whether or not the list is empty.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: Returns true if the list is empty, false otherwise.

    void print() const;
    // Function to display data in each node.
    // Precondition: Function is called.
    // Postcondition: None.

    int length() const;
    // Function to return the number of nodes in the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: The value of count is returned.

    void destroyList();
    // Function to delete all the nodes from the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;

    Type front() const;
    // Function to return the first element of the list.
    // Precondition: The list must exist and must not be empty.
    // Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program terminates. Otherwise,
    //                the first element of the list is returned.

    Type back() const;
    // Function to return the last element of the list.
    // Precondition: The list must exist and must not be empty.
    // Postcondition: If the list is empty, the program terminates. Otherwise,
    //                the last element of the list is returned.

    virtual bool search(const Type& searchItem) const = 0;
    // Function to determine whether or not the searchItem is in the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the list, false otherwise.

    virtual void insertFirst(const Type& newItem) = 0;
    // Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is inserted at the
    //                beginning of the list, last points to the last node in the
    //                list, and count is incremented by 1.

    virtual void insertLast(const Type& newItem) = 0;
    // Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is inserted at the
    //                end of the list, last points to the last node in the
    //                list, and count is incremented by 1.

    virtual void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem) = 0;
    // Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: If found, the node containing deleteItem is deleted from
    //                the list. first points to the first node, last points to the
    //                last node of the updated list, and coint is decremented by 1.

    LinkedListIterator<Type> begin();
    // Function to return an iterator at the beginning of the linked list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: Returns an iterator such that current is set to first.

    LinkedListIterator<Type> end();
    // Function to return an iterator one element past the last element of the linked list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: Returns an iterator such that current is set to NULL.

    LinkedList();
    // Default constructor initializes list to an empty state.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: first = NULL, last = NULL, count = 0;

    LinkedList(const LinkedList<Type>& otherList);
    // Copy constructor.

    ~LinkedList();
    // Destructor deletes all the nodes from the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: The list object is destoryed.

protected:

    int count; // Variable to store the number of list elements.

    nodeType<Type> *first; // Pointer to the first node of the list.
    nodeType<Type> *last;  // Pointer to the last node of the list.

private:
    void copyList(const LinkedList<Type>& otherList);
    // Function to make  copy of otherList.
    // Postcondition: A copy of otherList is created and assigned to the list.
};

#endif /* LinkedList_h */

#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "LinkedListIterator.h"
#include "nodeType.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class Type>
const LinkedList<Type>& LinkedList<Type>::operator=(const LinkedList<Type>& otherList)
{
    if(this != otherList)       // Avoid self-copy.
    {
        copyList(otherList);
    }

    return *this;
}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::initializeList()
{
    destroyList();              // If the list has any nodes, delete them.
}

template <class Type>
bool LinkedList<Type>::isEmptyList() const
{
    return first == NULL;
}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::print() const
{
    nodeType<Type> *current;    // Pointer to traverse the list.

    current = first;            // Point current to the first node.

    while(current != NULL)      // While there is data to print.
    {
        std::cout << current->info << " ";
        current = current->link;
    }
}

template <class Type>
int LinkedList<Type>::length() const
{
    return count;
}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::destroyList()
{
    nodeType<Type> *temp;       // Pointer to deallocate memory occupied by the node.

    while(first != NULL)        // While there are nodes in the list.
    {
        temp = first;           // Set temp to current node.
        first = first->link;    // Advance first to the next node.
        delete temp;            // Deallocate memory occupied by temp.
    }

    last = nullptr;             // Initialize last to NULL.

    count = 0;                  // Set count to 0.
}

template <class Type>
Type LinkedList<Type>::front() const
{
    assert(first != NULL);

    return first->info;         // Return the info of the first node.
}

template <class Type>
Type LinkedList<Type>::back() const
{
    assert(last != NULL);

    return last->info;         // Return the info of the last node.
}

template <class Type>
bool LinkedList<Type>::search(const Type& searchItem) const
{

}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type& newItem)
{

}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type& newItem)
{

}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
{

}

template <class Type>
LinkedListIterator<Type> LinkedList<Type>::begin()
{
    LinkedListIterator<Type> temp(first);

    return temp;
}

template <class Type>
LinkedListIterator<Type> LinkedList<Type>::end()
{
    LinkedListIterator<Type> temp(NULL);

    return temp;
}

template <class Type>
LinkedList<Type>::LinkedList()
{
    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    count = 0;
}

template <class Type>
LinkedList<Type>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<Type>& otherList)
{
    first = NULL;
    copyList(otherList);
}

template <class Type>
LinkedList<Type>::~LinkedList()
{
    destroyList();
}

template <class Type>
void LinkedList<Type>::copyList(const LinkedList<Type>& otherList)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;                    // Pointer to create a node.
    nodeType<Type> *currentNode;                // Pointer to traverse the list.

    if(first != NULL)                           // If the list is not empty, empty it.
    {
        destroyList();
    }

    if(otherList.first == NULL)                 // If otherList is empty.
    {
        first = NULL;
        last = NULL;
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        currentNode = otherList.first;          // currentNode points to the list to be copied.

        count = otherList.count;

        // Copy the first node.
        first = new nodeType<Type>;             // Create the node.
        first->info = currentNode->info;        // Copy the info.
        first->link = NULL;                     // Set link to NULL.
        last = first;                           // Make last point to first node.
        currentNode = currentNode->link;        // Make currentNode point to the next node.

        // Copy the rest of the list.
        while(currentNode != NULL)
        {
            newNode = new nodeType<Type>;       // Create a new node.
            newNode = currentNode->info;        // Copy the info.
            newNode->link = NULL;               // Set newNode link to NULL.    
            last->link = newNode;               // Attach newNode to end of list.
            last = newNode;                     // Make last point to last node.
            currentNode = currentNode->link;    // Make currentNode point to the next node.
        }
    }
}

#ifndef LinkedListIterator_h
#define LinkedListIterator_h

#include "nodeType.h"

template<class Type>
class LinkedListIterator
{
public:
    LinkedListIterator();
    // Default constructor.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: current = NULL;

    LinkedListIterator(nodeType<Type> *ptr);
    // Constructor that accepts a nodeType object and points current to it.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: current = ptr;

    Type operator*();
    // Function to overload the dereferencing operator *.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: Returns the info contained in the node.

    LinkedListIterator<Type> operator++();
    // Function to overload the preincrement operator.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: The iterator is advanced to the next node.

    bool operator==(const LinkedListIterator<Type>& right) const;
    // Function to overload the equality operator.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: Returns true if this iterator is equal to the iterator
    //                specified by the right, false otherwise.

    bool operator!=(const LinkedListIterator<Type>& right) const;
    // Function to overload the not equal to operator.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: Returns true if this iterator is not equal to the iterator
    //                specified by the right, false otherwise.

private:
    nodeType<Type> *currentNode;        // Pointer to point to the current node in the list.
};

#endif /* LinkedListIterator_h */

#include "LinkedListIterator.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class Type>
LinkedListIterator<Type>::LinkedListIterator()
{
    currentNode = NULL;
}

template <class Type>
LinkedListIterator<Type>::LinkedListIterator(nodeType<Type> *ptr)
{
    currentNode = ptr;
}

template <class Type>
Type LinkedListIterator<Type>::operator*()
{
    return currentNode->info;
}

template <class Type>
LinkedListIterator<Type> LinkedListIterator<Type>::operator++()
{
    currentNode = currentNode->link;
}

template <class Type>
bool LinkedListIterator<Type>::operator==(const LinkedListIterator<Type> &right) const
{
    return (currentNode == right.currentNode);
}

template <class Type>
bool LinkedListIterator<Type>::operator!=(const LinkedListIterator<Type> &right) const
{
    return (currentNode != right.currentNode);
}

#ifndef UnorderedLinkedList_h
#define UnorderedLinkedList_h

#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "nodeType.h"
#include <iostream>

template <class Type>
class UnorderedLinkedList: public LinkedList<Type>
{
public:
    bool search(const Type& searchItem) const;
    // Function to determine whether or not the searchItem is in the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: Returns true if searchItem is in the list, false otherwise.

    void insertFirst(const Type& newItem);
    // Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is inserted at the
    //                beginning of the list, last points to the last node in the
    //                list, and count is incremented by 1.

    void insertLast(const Type& newItem);
    // Function to insert newItem at the beginning of the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: first points to the new list, newItem is inserted at the
    //                end of the list, last points to the last node in the
    //                list, and count is incremented by 1.

    void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem);
    // Function to delete deleteItem from the list.
    // Precondition:
    // Postcondition: If found, the node containing deleteItem is deleted from
    //                the list. first points to the first node, last points to the
    //                last node of the updated list, and coint is decremented by 1.

};
#endif /* UnorderedLinkedList_h */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "UnorderedLinkedList.h"

template <class Type>
bool UnorderedLinkedList<Type>::search(const Type &searchItem) const
{
    nodeType<Type> *currentNode;                // Pointer to traverse the list.
    bool found = false;

    currentNode = LinkedList<Type>::first;      // Set currentNode to point to the first node in the list.

    while(currentNode != NULL && !found)        // Search the list.
    {
        if(currentNode->info == searchItem)     // If seachItem is found.
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->link;    // Makes current point to the next node.
        }
    }
}

template <class Type>
void UnorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertFirst(const Type &newItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;                    // Pointer to create the new node.

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;               // Create the new node.
    newNode->info = newItem;                    // Store the new item in the node.
    newNode->link = LinkedList<Type>::first;                // Insert newNode before first.
    LinkedList<Type>::first = newNode;                      // Make first point to the actual first node.
    LinkedList<Type>::count++;                              // Increment count.

    if(LinkedList<Type>::last == NULL)                     // If the list was empty, newNode is also the last node.
    {
        LinkedList<Type>::last = newNode;
    }
}

template <class Type>
void UnorderedLinkedList<Type>::insertLast(const Type &newItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;                    // Pointer to create the new node.

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;               // Create the new node.
    newNode->info = newItem;                    // Store the new item in the node.
    newNode->link = NULL;                       // Set the link of newNode to NULL.

    if(LinkedList<Type>::first == NULL)                     // If the list is empty, insert newNode after last.
    {
        LinkedList<Type>::first = newNode;
        LinkedList<Type>::last = newNode;
        LinkedList<Type>::count++;                          // Increment count.
    }
    else
    {
        LinkedList<Type>::last->link = newNode;             // Insert newNode after last.
        LinkedList<Type>::last = newNode;                   // Make last point to the actual last node in the list.
        LinkedList<Type>::count++;                          // Increment count.
    }
}

template <class Type>
void UnorderedLinkedList<Type>::deleteNode(const Type &deleteItem)
{
    nodeType<Type> *currentNode;                // Pointer for traversing the list.
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent;               // Pointer just before current.
    bool found;

    if(LinkedList<Type>::first == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if(this->first->info == deleteItem)
        {
            currentNode = LinkedList<Type>::first;
            LinkedList<Type>::first = LinkedList<Type>::first->link;
            LinkedList<Type>::count++;

            if(LinkedList<Type>::first == NULL)
            {
                LinkedList<Type>::last = NULL;
            }

            delete currentNode;
        }
        else                                    // Search the list for the node with the given info.
        {
            found = false;
            trailCurrent = LinkedList<Type>::first;         // Set trailCurrent to point to the first node.
            currentNode = LinkedList<Type>::first->link;    // Set currentNode to point to the second node.

            while(currentNode != NULL && !found)
            {
                if(currentNode->info != deleteItem)
                {
                    trailCurrent = currentNode;
                    currentNode = currentNode->link;
                }
                else
                {
                   found = true;
            }
        }

        if(found)                           // If found, delete the node.
        {
            trailCurrent->link = currentNode->link;
            LinkedList<Type>::count--;

            if(LinkedList<Type>::ast == currentNode)   // Node to be deleted was the last node.
            {
                LinkedList<Type>::last = trailCurrent;  // Update the value of last.
            }

            delete currentNode;             // Delete the node from the list.
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the list.\n";
        }
    }
}
}

#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "UnorderedLinkedList.h"

int main()
{
UnorderedLinkedList<int> list1, list2;
int num;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if(i == 0)
    {
        list1.insertFirst(num);
    }
    else
    {
        list1.insertLast(num);
    }
}

list1.print();

return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "LinkedList<int>::LinkedList()", referenced from:
      UnorderedLinkedList<int>::UnorderedLinkedList() in main.o
  "LinkedList<int>::~LinkedList()", referenced from:
      UnorderedLinkedList<int>::~UnorderedLinkedList() in main.o
  "UnorderedLinkedList<int>::deleteNode(int const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for UnorderedLinkedList<int> in main.o
  "UnorderedLinkedList<int>::insertLast(int const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      vtable for UnorderedLinkedList<int> in main.o
  "UnorderedLinkedList<int>::insertFirst(int const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
      vtable for UnorderedLinkedList<int> in main.o
  "LinkedList<int>::print() const", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "UnorderedLinkedList<int>::search(int const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for UnorderedLinkedList<int> in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I copied the above code, aside from the main, right from the textbook. The main wasn't copied from the textbook, though it might as well have been. I'm just trying to get it working before making the required changes for the homework assignment, but it's not happening. Any input would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, though I still don't know what was wrong with the code. Two professors looked at it and couldn't see anything wrong, and eventually, I learned that source code was available. I downloaded and compared it to what I have. It was identical except that it included the implementation code in the header files, which should make no difference. At any rate, it's no longer an issue.